# CryptoStream - Read vs Write - Is there any difference?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, cryptostream

Is there any change in the code needed between if we use `CryptoStream` with `CryptoStreamMode.Read` or with `CryptoStreamMode.Write` ?

(Besides reading from it and writing to an `outStream` or reading from an `inStream` and writing to the `CryptoStream`, of course.)

.

.

If you absolutely need to see code, here's some (See end of 3rd line):

```
using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
using (ICryptoTransform encryptorTransform = aes.CreateEncryptor())
using (CryptoStream outAesStream = new CryptoStream(outStream, encryptorTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: There is a breaking change in `CryptoStream.Read` in .net 6 if you are looking for that - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/partial-byte-reads-in-streams

Comment: Don't think so. Generally I'd use `CryptoStream.Write` for encryption and `CryptoStream.Read` for decryption. You're not likely to perform any non-streaming ops on the ciphertext after all. Beware of plaintext oracle attacks though, you might want to perform an integrity / authenticity check before decrypting and/or handling message (see e.g. padding & plaintext oracle attacks).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I've actually found a difference - it seems like we need `FlushFinalBlock ` only when using Write, not when using Read. Probably to let the `CryptoStream` pad the data. To let it know we don't have any more data to be written to it.

Comment: As for additional operations on the Stream - I'm trying to incorporate writing and reading the salt through the Stream overriding its `Read` method.

Comment: @ispiro I guess you could bring the flushing down to generic issues with write and read. For read you never need to flush anyway. But yeah, there is some asymmetry there.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks. I guess the bottom line is as you said, that there is no qualitative difference between Read and Write. You can transform your comment(s) into an answer.